# Getting application errors on Azure I dont get locally

Tags: python, azure, flask, pymongo, mongoengine

I am developing a Flask/MongoDB application Im deploying on Azure. Locally, I am in the process of creating my models and testing my database connection. I am using [Flask-MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/projects/flask-mongoengine/en/latest/) to manage my DB connection. This is a sample of code that works perfectly on `localhost` but fails when calling its deployed version on Azure.

```
# On models.py

from flask_mongoengine import MongoClient
db = MongoClient()

class User(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=50)
    token  = db.StringField(max_length=50)
    email  = db.EmailField()
```

Later, from `views.py` I call my User class like this:

```
import models as mdl

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    """For testing purposes"""
    user = mdl.User(name='Matias')
    user.save()
    users = mdl.User.objects
    return jsonify(users)
```

which ouputs as expected locally. On Azure, however, I get the following error 
(will only show the last and relevant part of the traceback):

```
File ".\app\views.py", line 53, in test
    user = mdl.User(name='Matias')
  File "D:\home\python364x86\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", 
line 43, in _init_
    self._initialised = False
  File "D:\home\python364x86\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", 
line 168, in _setattr_
    self._is_document and
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute '_is_document'
```

Through `pip freeze` I checked I am using the same versions for `mongoengine`, `pymongo` and `flask_mongoengine` in both environments. I can't seem to find someone else with the same problem. The app is deployed as a webapp on a Windows machine in the Azure cloud.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**PS: Further info**
Reviewing `mongoengine` code, I found out that `_is_document` attribute is set inside a metaclass for the class `Document` (`DocumentMetaclass` and `TopLevelDocumentMetaclass`). I tried setting the attribute to `True` inside `User`, and the following error showed:
`AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute '_meta'`,
which is also an attribute defined inside those metaclasses. Somehow the metaclasses code is not running? Maybe the Azure environment has something to do with it?

Comment: Your trace back doesn’t match your code.

Comment: Check that you've got the same versions of Mongo and the flask_mongoengine library installed on Azure as you do locally

Comment: @TimThompson I have. I also got rid of `flask-mongoengine`  and implemented the same solution using pure `mongoengine`, got the same error. Have `pymongo 3.4.0` and `mongoengine 0.15.0` in both environments. I am at wits end.